# DataFrame serialization across PySpark and JVM

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I have a Scala code:

```
package com.mycompany

object Helper {

    def process(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
        // do some processing and return processed dataframe
    }
}
```

Above class is packaged into a JAR and added to PySpark's classpath.

Now from PySpark, I can use above method to do processing on PySpark's dataframe as:

```
# JVM version of Python DataFrame through the use of the _jdf property
scala_processed_jdf = sc._jvm.com.mycompany.Helper().process(df._jdf)
```

Also the scala version of dataframe returned from above function can be wrapped to pyspark dataframe as:

```
DataFrame(scala_processed_jdf, sqlContext)
```

As I understand, PySpark uses Py4j to communicate between Python and JVM.

1. But how is this pyspark's version of dataframe sent to the JVM ?
2. Does the entire dataframe gets serialized before sending to JVM and de-serialized back when sent to PySpark, or just the reference `df._jdf` is sent to JVM ?
3. What is the serialization library PySpark uses internally to do this ? And how much is the overhead added by this SerDe ?
4. Is it a good practice to pass dataframe around between PySpark and JVM as shown above ?

Please help. Thanks.